# Graphical intuition for the remainder of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to understand the graphical intuition for the remainder $R_n$ of a series by studying [Paul’s online notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/EstimatingSeries.aspx) (specifically, my question relates to the two pictures on the linked web page). First, these pictures are confusing to me as it looks like the value of the Riemann sum  $R_n$ is different between each picture rather the area of the integrals $\int_n^\infty f(x)dx$ and $\int_{n+1}^\infty f(x)dx$. I’m assuming that the Riemann sum is shifted to the left by one term in the bottom picture, but please tell me if I am wrong. Assuming that I understand everything correctly so far, I am still uncertain as to why the following statement is true. $$R_n \le \int_n^\infty f(x)dx$$ I understand why this is true if I can always assume that $R_n$ corresponds to a right endpoint Riemann sum. If $R_n$ is a right Riemann sum and $f(x)$ is decreasing, then each rectangle ends at a point on the curve and doesn’t overestimate the area. But why can I assume that $\int_n^\infty f(x)dx$ corresponds to a right endpoint Riemann sum rather than a left endpoint Riemann sum?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  They stated assuming that the series terms are all positive and decreasing; in that case, the area of the rectangles (which is $R_n$) is less than or equal to the integral from $n$ to $\infty$

Comment: "They stated assuming that the series terms are all positive and decreasing; in that case, the area of the rectangles (which is $R_n$) is less than or equal to the integral from $n$ to $\infty$" I know they stated that this is true but what is the reasoning behind it? It seems like a left Riemann sum, if possible in this context, would refute this statement. Is there a reason then that a left Riemann sum is impossible?

Comment: If you look at the picture, you'll see that, when the terms are positive and decreasing, it's right -- the heights of the rectangles match the height of the curve on their right side; remember:  the sum for $R_n$ starts with $a_{n\color{red}{+1}}$

Comment: Knowing that $R_n$ begins with $a_{n+1}$ clears everything up, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the link you provided, this integral test of convergence works for a non-negative function that is *decreasing.*  Under that assumption, the sum of the areas of the rectangles shown in the picture in the link (i.e., $R_n$) is less than or equal to the integral from $n$ to $\infty$.  Keep in mind that the sum for $R_n$ starts with $a_{n\color{red}{+1}}.$  These conditions make it a *right* Riemann sum.